# Prevent converting a Single to the Scientific Numbers format

Tags: vba, number-formatting

There is

```
Dim sValA as Single
sValA = 10140000
```

When I perform: `Debug.Print sValA`,

Returns: `1.014E+07`

I need *never converting a Single number to the scientific format*. (Means: 10140000 should be returns)

Comment: Why are you using a `Single` to store high numeric values (without any decimal in it) ? you can use `Long`, and then `Debug.Print sValA` will return `10140000`.